# Android: Proguard error in eclipse

Tags: android, proguard, android-support-library, android-proguard

I am trying to built the signed apk of my app. But i am getting the error pop up as

```
Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
```

And error log in console as :

```
[2016-04-15 11:36:44 - MyApp] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2016-04-15 11:36:44 - MyApp] Note: there were 85 duplicate class definitions.
[2016-04-15 11:36:44 - MyApp] Warning: org.acra.ErrorReporter: can't find referenced method 'void setLatestEventInfo(android.content.Context,java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence,android.app.PendingIntent)' in class android.app.Notification
[2016-04-15 11:36:44 - MyApp]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2016-04-15 11:36:44 - MyApp] Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to program class members.
[2016-04-15 11:36:44 - MyApp]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
[2016-04-15 11:36:44 - MyApp]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
[2016-04-15 11:36:44 - MyApp]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
[2016-04-15 11:36:44 - MyApp]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
[2016-04-15 11:36:44 - MyApp] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2016-04-15 11:36:44 - MyApp]   at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2016-04-15 11:36:44 - MyApp]   at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2016-04-15 11:36:44 - MyApp]   at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2016-04-15 11:36:44 - MyApp]   at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

I am not able to understand what is the issue. For last version it works fine. I just provide support to Marsh Mellow in this version.

Please suggest me what changes or steps to perform to built signed apk with out Proguard error.

Comment: Please show use your proguard rules

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to Proguard configuration file:

```
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn android.net.**
```