# generate singed apk error

Tags: android, gradle, apk, proguard, android-proguard

not generate singed apk. but not error when run app.

When running ProGuard on our Application and generate apk we see the following warning.

```
Warning:com.localytics.android.SessionHandler$15: can't find referenced method 'void setLatestEventInfo(android.content.Context,java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence,android.app.PendingIntent)' in library class android.app.Notification
Warning:there were 1 unresolved references to library class members.
     You probably need to update the library versions.
     (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

Answer (score 0):

[The problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639689/android-proguard-error-in-eclipse) is obviously setLatestEventInfo [and a quick search](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/issues/437) shows this is the result of a bug/deprecation problem. See the links or search "setLatestEventInfo"

Comment: not working (-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn android.net.**  )

Comment: You could try putting-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn android.net.**

Answer (score 0):

You might have set `minifyEnabled = true`, if so... then please set below mentioned line in proguard (**proguard-rules.pro** file).

```
  -dontwarn android.app.Notification
```